# How to make animation adapt to different screen size? Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I created this animation in a 4-inch size storyboard. How can I make sure the ratio stays the same when it adapts to let's say an iPhone 6. I'm not talking about Auto-Layout or constraints. I added the animation code below. 
This works the way I want it in a 4-inch size, but again, When I resize everything for iPhone 6, Everything looks fine, besides the animation itself. How can I fix this?

```
@IBAction func chimneySmoke(sender: UIButton) {

        let smokeOne = UIImageView()
        smokeOne.image = UIImage(named: "smoke1a")
        smokeOne.frame = CGRect(x: -145, y: 160, width: 20, height: 20)
        self.view.addSubview(smokeOne)

        let randomXOffset = CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(40))

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 140,y: 172))
        path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 150 + randomXOffset, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 158 + randomXOffset, y: 90), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 146 + randomXOffset, y: 60))

        let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        anim.path = path.CGPath
        anim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto
        anim.duration = 9.0
        smokeOne.layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "animate position along path")

    }
```

Comment: Make the values as percentages rather than hard coded numbers

Comment: Ok, could you please give an example using the code I provided. I just want to make sure I understand it correctly. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accomplish this by making the values as percentages rather than hard coded numbers. To do this, you need a fraction multiplied by `frame.width` or `frame.height`. Your fraction, if you have base units (ie. you're developing on a screen that is 320 by 640), should be the value you want divided by the length in that direction. For example if your screen width is 320 and you want the point 145, the value will be `145 / 320 * frame.width` so when your screen width becomes different (lets say iPad so 768 points) the point will still be in the same spot on the screen as a percentage.

```
smokeOne.frame = CGRect(x: -145 / 320 * frame.width, y: 160 / 640 * frame.height, width: 20 / 320 * frame.width, height: 20 / 640 * frame.height)
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I really appreciate you taking time to explain this. This is very helpful !

Comment: For some reason it is giving me an error saying : Use of unresolved identifier 'frame'. Any idea how that's possible?

Comment: well frame.width refers to whatever view you want the percentage to be based on. it'll probably be `someView.frame.width`

Comment: You got me lost there. So what view are we talking about? Do I need to define my background view in the function because that background view is covering the entire storyboard view controller? I'm just guessing here because I'm confused.

Comment: It can be any view with a frame dependent on the screen size of the device